# Create a work profile on emulator

Tags: android, encryption

I'm trying to use the Basic Managed Profile sample app and create a (work) profile on emulator running Android L. This procedure requires device encryption, which doesn't seem to work on emulator.

Is there a way to bypass the encryption and create the profile?

Or is there a way to make the encryption succeed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Emulator encryption does not work due to battery not enough to encrypt.
Emulator battery status can be changed using below adb commands,

```
telnet localhost 5554

power capacity 100
OK
```

After running above commands in ADB, try running the *BasicManagedProfile*it should be able to encrypt the emulator.

Comment: Does not work for me on current version. The barrery is allready 100% as default.